# How to add a WYSIWYG editor to Magento custom options

Tags: php, magento, editor, wysiwyg

Im trying to implement a wysiwyg editor under text-option in Magentos custom options, but am failing there. I have already searched for several components, but can't get it together though.

I want that editor to appear in the field where the WYSIWYG Value-textarea is right now.
[image: screenshot of: WYSIWYG shall appear in textarea]

Other source either don't go into detail or aren't working for 1.9.1.

What I have so far: [WR is companyname and EPO is my module]

I've found this snippet, which is used to place a wysiwyg editor on a cms page within a _prepareForm function:

```
<?php
    if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled() && ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'))) {
        $block->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
    }

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
        'method' => 'post'
    ));
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
        'legend' => Mage::helper('wr_epo')->__("Some Information"),
        'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
    ));
    $wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config');
    $fieldset->addField('description', 'editor', array(
        'name' => 'description',
        'label' => Mage::helper('wr_epo')->__('Description'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('wr_epo')->__('Description'),
        'style' => 'height: 600px;',
        'wysiwyg' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'config' => $wysiwygConfig
    ));?>
```

Comment: The `$block->setCanLoadTinyMce(true)` should be within a prepare_layout function.  Have you combined it here for ease of reading? (if not, it should be moved).  Looks like you've followed http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-wysiwyg-editor-to-admin-form/ but taken a short cut, as layout will likely already be added at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue like this no to long ago (client wanted custom stuff in an option).
I dont know if this is exactly what you want. But heres what i did:

I made a php file in the root of my magento.

And then i added this code. I found it on stackoverflow. If anyone knows where it comes from be even better.

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');


function createNewAttributeSet($name) {
    Mage::app('default');
    $modelSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->setEntityTypeId(4) // 4 == "catalog/product"
    ->setAttributeSetName($name);
    $modelSet->save();
    $modelSet->initFromSkeleton(4)->save(); // same thing
}

// Replace your attribute name with "extra_info"

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'extra_info', array(
        'group'             => 'General Information',
        'type'              => 'text',
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'Extra Information',
        'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
        'input'             => 'textarea',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'           => 1,
        'required'          => 0,
        'user_defined'      => 0,
        'default'           => '',
        'searchable'        => 0,
        'filterable'        => 0,
        'comparable'        => 0,
        'visible_on_front'  => 0,
        'unique'            => 0,
        'position'          => 1,
));
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'extra_info', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'extra_info', 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 1);
```

I do however Think you want to include

```
'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
```

Rather than

```
 'wysiwyg' => true,
```

(this is refering to your code you pasted earlier)

Other reading:

Things i found that helped with my issues:
https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/
https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html

Comment: This is just adding an attribute but you also need to do many other things like editing the adminhtml template files and overriding conrollers.